# VBA adding chart title

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I simply want to add a chart title to my chart using vba. I actually want to do it recursively for every chart in every sheet, but I can't even get 1 chart to work. Here is the code I have:

```
Dim chnam
chnam = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, (Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 9))
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle = chnam
End With
```

Here is my chart:

[image]

When I run my code, I get:

```
Object does not support this property or method
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I am using Excel 2007

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim chnam as string
chnam = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, (Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 9))
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Select
    .ChartTitle.Text = chnam
End With
```

Comment: Edited my answer, please try the new code. If it fails again please run in debug mode and tell me which line is failing.

Comment: The chart is active when you are doing this yes?

Comment: By active if you mean that the chart is already there, then yes, it is active.

Also, I ran it in debug mode and it fails in the with statement. When I tried arcadecomputing's code, it fails in the .HasTitle = True part

Comment: By active I mean is it the active object ie as if you have clicked on it, run your code line by line by pressing F8 and just before the with statement click on the chart then continue the code and post back with the results

Comment: I also tried running this code in a completely new and separate workbook to make sure my other code wasn't interfering and the same issue is present

Comment: Cool you just need to select it with code now, easy enough if you know the chart object name, post back if you get stuck

Comment: Nope, everything works well. I got the loop going and it's perfect. Thanks

Comment: FYI, the ".ChartTitle.Select" is superfluous

Comment: Shorten `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ActiveChart` to `ActiveChart`.

Comment: ... or use 'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to this:

```
Dim chnam As String

chnam = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, (Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 9))

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Select
    .ChartTitle.Text = chnam
End With
```

...which will work for the active chart, then add a `For Each`... if you want to apply to all charts in all sheets in the activeworkbook.

Comment: it fails in the .HasTitle = True part

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and can't find the answer - but have found something that works.  What I mean by that is I don't know why it works but it does.

Try this - worked for me.:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
.HasTitle = False // added line - not sure why it works!
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart Title"
End With
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart` to `ActiveChart`.

Answer (score 0):

The above failed for me in Office 2016.  I had to use the Worksheet.Shapes object.

```
Debug.Assert ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Count = 0 ' Strange, but true
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Text = chnam
```

The following subroutine works for me.

```
' Set title of chart with given name on given worksheet
Private Sub RetitleChart(sheetExport As Worksheet, strChartName As String, strChartTitle As String)
  Dim chartOverview As Chart

  Set chartOverview = sheetExport.Shapes(strChartName).Chart
  chartOverview.ChartTitle.Text = strChartTitle
  Set chartOverview = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Charts` counts the chart sheets in the workbook, and ignores any chart objects embedded in sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Your code ought to be `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Text = chnam` but it will fail unless the chart already has a title.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to set a Chart's Title text is to use the ChartWizard method, thus:

```
Dim chnam as string
chnam = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, (Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 9))
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ActiveChart.ChartWizard Title:=chnam
```

It's worthwhile familiarizing yourself with the documentation for this method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838804.aspx

and that of Chart itself:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837379.aspx

(Which has a link to the documentation for the ChartTitle object.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - on my current machine, Excel 2017, while I hadn't had it 6 months ago; having code

```
pchrTheChart.HasTitle = True
pchrTheChart.ChartTitle.Select
```

would err on the second line; if I inserted a breakpoint and then resumed with no change, it worked fine.

But, variant on a solution above worked; even though the chart was just created and started out without a title, I have to explicitly turn the title off before turning it on and now it works with no issues every time.

```
pchrTheChart.HasTitle = False
pchrTheChart.HasTitle = True
pchrTheChart.ChartTitle.Select
```

Original poster said they didn't know why it worked; answer, to me it seems we're working around a VBA bug, I imagine something to do with null handling.