# Unable to get the 'Date' right on the X axis when trying to plot several different plots via a loop

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

newbie programmer here:

I have this big data set (Excel file) on gas, hydro, and water bills per unit from 2017 to 2020 for each building.
Basically, the first column is the date column, and each subsequent column has the building name as the title of the column which contains the cost/unit for that particular building.

So there are 61 buildings, hence 61 columns, plus the date column bringing the total # of columns to 62. I am trying to make 62 individual plots of "cost/unit vs time", whereby I want my cost/unit to be on the y axis and the date(time) to be on the x axis.

I think I am getting the plots right, I am just not able to figure out why my dates don't come the way they should on the x axis.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stat
import numpy as np
import math as mt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime


df1 = pd.read_csv('Gas Costs.csv')

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%m-%y')
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')

for column in df1:
   columnSeriesObj = df1[column]
   plt.plot(columnSeriesObj.values)
   plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
   plt.show()
```

By doing this, I get 61 plots, one of which looks like this:
[Cost/unit v/s time plot for one of the buildings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htkcy.png)

I also wish to give each plot a title stating the building name, but I am unable to do so. I tried it using the for loop but didn't strike much luck with it.

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: Update: Got the dates, Still stuck on the titles

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616464/vba-adding-chart-title)

Comment: Update: I was able to figure it out now, let me know if someone wants to see my code!